# C# Socket connection error

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I'm working with sockets in C# and I'm getting the following error:

> A request to send or receive data was
>   disallowed because the socket is not
>   connected and (when sending on a
>   datagram socket using a sendto call)
>   no address was supplied

Here is the code that I'm executing:

```
    private void HostSubscriberService()
    {
        IPAddress ipV4 = PublisherService.ReturnMachineIP();

        var localEP = new IPEndPoint(ipV4, _port);
        var server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        server.Bind(localEP);

        StartListening(server);
    }

    private void StartListening(Socket server)
    {
        EndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        while (true)
        {
            var data = new byte[1024];
            int recv = server.ReceiveFrom(data, ref remoteEP);
            string messageSendFromClient = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);

            MessageBox.Show(messageSendFromClient);
        }
    }
```

The error happens @ `int recv = server.ReceiveFrom(data, ref remoteEP);`

I just need to listen for new incoming connections and then print the message that was sent from the new client.

I need it to work on the TCP protocol, because some of the messages will be > 1500 bytes

Thanks!

Comment: Dude, ReceiveFrom() is for UDP, use Accept() and Receive() for TCP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to .BeginAccept() before you can receive.

[Here's a link with a sinple Asynchronous Socket Server example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f.aspx)

Comment: Ah!  ok, `ReceiveFrom` is UDP.  Is there any way to get the `EndPoint` from a connected client using TCP?

Comment: @joe_coolish: [RemoteEndPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.remoteendpoint.aspx) MSDN is your friend :)

Answer (score 1):

ReceiveFrom() is for UDP, use Accept() and Receive() for TCP